# Jenkins Declarative pipeline: send email notification with test report in post stage

Tags: java, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

I have a simple pipeline script with two stages (test stage and post-stage) in the post-stage, where I send a notification if the build is failed or unstable. However, I am able to send a notification with job name, build number and the console output of that job in the notification but I also need to send the link of the failing test report in the notification itself (I have the test reports in the workspace folder in Jenkins as HTML file)

For this, I have a developed a groovy script (see test.groovy) but I am not sure how to add this to the pipeline script in post-stage in the mail block (in the post-stage)

pipeline script

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy
@Library(['piper-lib', 'piper-lib-os']) _
 
 
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        
        stage('Campaign Log') { 
            
            steps {
                echo "RUNNING ${env.BUILD_ID} on ${env.JENKINS_URL}"
                uiVeri5ExecuteTests script: this,
                testRepository: "https://github.wdf.sap.corp/grc-iag-acert/qa.ui.automation.wdf.git",
                gitBranch: "sg-pipeline",
                testOptions: "-v --params.user='iag.administrator.testing@sap.com' --params.pass='Iagadministrator123@\$' ./logs/campaign_log/config.js --baseUrl=https://parrot-one-flp-iag-acert-qa-hcl.cfapps.sap.hana.ondemand.com/cp.portal/site#Shell-home"
            }
        }
        
    }
    
    post {  
         failure {  
             //def console_output = "${env.BUILD_URL}/console" 
             mail bcc: '', body: "Details: ${env.JOB_NAME} Build Number: ${env.BUILD_NUMBER} Build: ${env.BUILD_URL} Console Output: ${env.BUILD_URL}/console", cc: '', from: 'noreply+jaas@sap.com', replyTo: '', subject: 'Failing UIVeri5 Tests', to: 'surendra.gurram@sap.com'
         }  
         unstable {  
             mail bcc: '', body: "Details: ${env.JOB_NAME} Build Number: ${env.BUILD_NUMBER} Build: ${env.BUILD_URL} Console Output: ${env.BUILD_URL}/console", cc: '', from: 'noreply+jaas@sap.com', replyTo: '', subject: 'Failing UIVeri5 Tests', to: 'surendra.gurram@sap.com'
         }  
         
     }  
}
```

test.groovy (The code I developed to add in post-stage)

```
test = new File($ {env.BUILD_URL} + '/execution/node/3/ws/logs/campaign_log/target/report/report.html').readLines()[160]

check = test.substring(18, test.length() - 7);

if (0 < check.toInteger()) {
    println($ {env.BUILD_URL} + '/execution/node/3/ws/logs/campaign_log/target/report/report.html');

} else {
    println("this test passed");
}
```

BTW I am pretty new to Jenkins and pipeline script, and I am stuck here, could someone help me here.

Comment: You can publish your HTML report, then give the report link mail body. Here is exaple to publish HTML report https://www.jenkins.io/blog/2017/02/10/declarative-html-publisher/

Comment: thanks. However,  I have several stages and each stage (7 stages in total) have a test case and every test case have an HTML report. So, I want to send the link of the failing HTML report in the mail body but using this "publishHTML" I guess the report link will be hardcoded and I don't want to do that, as I said I have several stages (that means several reports) so I want the link of failing test report in the mail body.

Comment: I think the failing HTML report generated on the machine where your job run on. Thus those HTML reports are local file on disk, how you can assign link like HTTP URL for them. Even you can use FILE protocol URL like `file://....`, how you can click the url in mail to open them.

Comment: That's why i said to use publish HTML which will publish your HTML report to a web server (Actually it's the Jenkins Master Server).  You can disable the `Always link to latest build`, then it will keep URL in each build.

Comment: You can add a post step in each test stage. So you would be able catch the failure at the stage it happened and send the mail there.

Comment: @TaiLy Thanks for the response 

when I add multiple Post steps for each stage then I have the error 

 
`WorkflowScript: 21: Expected a stage @ line 21, column 5.
17:34:15         post {  
17:34:15         ^
`

Could please help me here. Thanks agian

Comment: sorry @yong, still I don't understand how to use publishHTML because I need to declare the publishHTML in POST step (I have one post now) but as I said I several tests with different HTML reports how do I do that. Thanks

Comment: You have to put the post step into each stage e.g. ````stages { stage('stage 1') { steps {...} post{...} } stage('stage 2') { ... } }````